# To return the last value in a row for Date and Person to Action (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to construct 2 current status columns so as find the last values in each row in Excel:

- one for the last Date and the other for the last person who needs to act.

Please see the attached jpg To return the last values in a row for Date and Person to Act

I have tried to use the excel functions, namely, **INDEX** or **LOOKUP** but to no avail because of the 3 Remarks columns within the table.

I would appreciate it if you could advise me how to craft a VBA code to the above query.

**From LC TAN 2020-02-13**

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use the MAX function to return the latest date in the row?

Comment: To: dhumprheys_ thank you for your comments, I have tried MAX before, it works for Date only and I also have tried function like  =LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(B6:J8)),B6:J8)- it also works. 
But for Staus Actions, if i were to used  =LOOKUP("zzzzzz",B6:J6), the Status will return at Column M the remark such as "No comments yet" instead of Lawrence or Adam that i want.  Without the 3 remarks columns, i think the LOOKUP will work. 
So the only way i can think of is VBA code to cater for the above.  From LC Tan 2020-02-13

Comment: To: braX_ thanks for asking, I think I have replied your query based on my reply to dhumprheys_ i have been searching in stackoverflow library for this query since August 2019, and i have tried other websites to no avail. From Tan LC 2020-02-13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

- you can use `LOOKUP` to return the last element in an array
- **BUT** you have to ensure your array only has the elements that you want to consider

There is a variation of the `INDEX` function where you can enter an array for the column (or row) argument and return selected items.  You enter the array, or arra constant, in a format like:

`N(IF(1,*array or arrayConstant*))`

So, a formula that would work for your requirements would be:

```
L6:  =LOOKUP(2,1/LEN(INDEX($B6:$J6,N(IF(1,{2,5,8})))),INDEX($B6:$J6,N(IF(1,{2,5,8}))))
```

and fill down.

[image]

Comment: To: Ron Rosenfeld_thank you very much. It works for me now. This is the first i have seen how LOOKUP and INDEX can be used in one formula;  i am now amazed because it is at a higher and deeper level than i have ever come across. Thank you once again.  From Tan LC 2020-02-14.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX` for the date to find the latest date in that row.

You can then use `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP` to find the action with that date. i.e. lookup the date that `MAX` has returned in the first set of columns, and if that returns an error, look in the second. If the second returns an error, look in the third.

As per your sheet, the formula for L6 would be `=MAX(B5:I5)`

The formula for M6 would be `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L5,B5:C5,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L5,E5:F5,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(L5,H5:I5,2,FALSE)))`

You can then drag the cells down to populate the date and action for every row. You could achieve the same with VBA if you wanted to, but I would have thought that this is the easiest way to get the the desired result.

Comment: To: dhumphryes_Thank you very much. Both your functions (IFERROR, VLOOKUP) and Ron's (LOOKUP,INDEX) work equally beautifully. I am now amazed that there is more than one method of achieving the result. Thank you very much. I tried to tick green for u. But then the green tick will be gone from Ron's or vice versa.  How can i tick one green for you and one for Ron's?

Comment: @Lc Tan, you can upvote both answers, but you can only accept one as the best answer, so whichever one works best for you I guess!